# if $D_1\sim D_1'$ and $D_2\sim D_2'$, then we have $D_1+D_2\sim D_1'+D_2'$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm studying [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) and I'm trying to prove that if $D_1\sim D_1'$ and $D_2\sim D_2'$, then we have $D_1+D_2\sim D_1'+D_2'$.

If the the first two equivalences work, then we have

$$D_1+D_2=(f_1)+(f_2)+(D_1'+D_2')$$

If I take the rational function $z=f_1f_2$, do I solve the question?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. The valuations you use to define $(f)$ are all homomorphisms, hence so is the map $K(C)^* \to \operatorname{Div} C$.

Comment: @Hoot As I thought, thank you!